Openshift route to Kafka server
Is it possible to create Openshift route to Kafka server deployed in Openshift in order to connect Kafka from local machine using Kafka tool?
There is a Pod (Kafka, Zookeeper),
Service (ports for internal ssl - 9093, no-ssl - 9092 and external ssl - 29093, no-ssl - 29092 connections) and route with termination type “passthrough” trying to access 29093 port.
I’m trying to use Route host and port 443 to connect Kafka via Kafka tool (providing truststore and keystore files path, required passwords) but it  fails with timeout error.
It is necessary to add that oc port-forward <pod> 29093:29093 is working fine on the local machine. Also, there is no opportunity to use Strimzi.

No it is not possible to use a route for Kafka traffic. Routes are specific to HTTP/HTTPS.
For something like Kafka where you are going to want arbitrary persistent TCP connections you would have to use something like a LoadBalancer type service ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/ ), if your underlying infrastructure can support that. Otherwise, you'd have to use a NodePort type service ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ ).
EDIT:
OneCricketeer added a good comment that I wanted to add to the answer. Another option is to set up the route for TLS passthrough. See his comment for a link to some excellent instructions. Note that those instructions do require Strimzi (which you say is not an option). I’m sure it’s possible to configure the TLS manually though.
I still think that a LoadBalancer/NodePort is your better short term answer, but that blog post actually discusses and documents those approaches as well.

This blog disagrees https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/30/accessing-kafka-part-3/ but it requires HAProxy

Good article. I don’t know if it disagrees with me: I even considered talking about TLS passthrough, but that’s more than a simple change to the route. Especially since the OP specifically says that Strimzi is unavailable. However, I’ll update the answer to mention this.
